# Highcharts - How to export graphic server side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have read and re-read [this](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts) page about rendering images server side. I can't get my head over it. Searched for examples but all and all it never seems to be enough. So I'm back here asking you for a clear example of this or a pointer in the right direction.

These is what I have:

1. Rails 4.0.2 app
2. Some charts rendered with some code like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tostasqb/pun63/) jsfiddle
3. Phantomjs installed by [this gem](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem)
4. highcharts-convert.js somewhere in my apps directory

Now finally the problem. How the hell do I call the phantomjs so that the image gets saved on the server?

I tried like this:

```
json_data = "json from jsfiddle"
out_path = "/tmp/"
width = 900

Rails.logger.info %x[phantomjs /opt/projects/project_name/highcharts-convert.js -infile #{json_data} -outfile #{out_path} -width #{width} 2>&1]
```

The reason for calling this code is that I snooped around [this project](https://github.com/kbaum/highchart-image-api)

Anyone?

EDIT:: One more detail, when I execute the command the error is

> sh: phantomjs: command not found

Comment: Gave up. I ended up using highchart-image-api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is quite clear: Your bash cannot find the `phantomjs` executable. This is because you have installed `phantomjs` with the [phantomjs gem](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem) which did not put the executable in your PATH.

You have a few options to tackle this:

- Put the `phantomjs` in your PATH. From the gem's documentation it seems that it should be installed in `$HOME/.phantomjs/VERSION/PLATFORM`.
- Instead of using the `phantomjs` command use the full path to the executable (which is the one noted above).
- Using the gem's API you can run `phantomjs` commands. It would be something like:

  ```
   Phantomjs.run('./path/to/script.js')
  ```

  For more info check the [examples](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem#example).

Comment: ok, one step closer :) `Phantomjs.run` is the way to go but now how do I pass the highcharts-convert.js as well as my json (stringified) chart?

Comment: The `Phantomjs.run` command accepts multiple arguments. So I guess you just need to specify the list of parameters you would normally give to `phantomjs` as arguments.

Comment: As a side note it seems from the blog post you have been reading that the highcharts folks have already implemented all the phantomjs procedure you are trying to do and have published an API that can handle external requests that returns the appropriate images. I assume you need more customization than their solution.

Comment: I was trying not to have to install this additional API in the server and use phantojs integrated on my existent application. I tried adding some parameters and had no positive result. Anyways I tried out the API and it has a fairly nice response, so I guess I'll stick to this API if no alternative comes along.